# Geometry Nodes UV on Instanced faces

Tags: uv, geometry-nodes

I would like to have a grid and on each point I´m instancing a face.
[image]
[image]

Does anyone have a solution?

I donn´t have a clue how to apply an image Texture across all tiles.

Comment: do you want one image over all faces or one image per face?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want something like that?

I did nothing special as you can see I simply played with the scale value in the shader editor.
[image]

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for. It looks pretty simple and I wonder why I haven't found this solution?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Glad! I could help you